# How to assign an envelope sender

Tags: docusignapi

Help me please. There are several users in the docusign account. How to send an envelope from their name? What would an envelope be sent not on behalf of the administrator, but on behalf of the user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use DocuSign's `OAUTH` user Application or Service Integration to implement the same. [DocuSign Authentication Overview](https://docs.docusign.com/esign/guide/authentication/auth_overview.html) has details about each integration type.

`OAuth Authorization Code Grant` and `OAuth Implicit Grant` are suitable only for user applications because it requires an end user to authenticate with DocuSign.

`Service Integration Authentication` uses JSON Web Token (JWT) Profile for OAuth 2.0 Client Authentication and Authorization Grants (RFC 7523) to create an access token. It is ideal for service integrations that do not involve a user agent like a browser or web view control. The result is an access token that represents the application or an impersonated user.

Implementing either User Application or Service Integration, you need to get consent of the user for whom you want to send the envelope and envelope will be sent from that user's account and that user will become the sender of the envelope.